# How to make multisite with each database

Tags: wordpress

I want to make wordpress as multisite but I also want to make 2 database each of website. Is it possible to made it and how ?

I have look at hyperdb and multidb plugin but it is not maintained at least 2 years ago.

Comment: What purpos you need multisite ? As you have different database , you simply can use different installation.

Comment: I have one site that run as website and multisite is runing as intra for employments. Is it posible to split databases ? There old system is build upon multisite that's why I need to exactly same.

Comment: Yes it is possible, simply go for CONVERT MULTISITE TO SINGLE SITE tutorials , here one I have found, you may find more easy instructions https://wordpress.org/support/topic/move-from-multi-site-to-single-site/

Comment: okay but is it possible to share users between this to sites ?

Comment: With MySQL commands, you can split content and keep specific content (like users) on both databases. I don't think it's possible by any plugin.

Comment: Hi, I have take decision to made 2 separate Wordpress system instead. It's must correct mode to do that. thanks for help.